# Springer LaTeX template for Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery journal

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, templates

I need to submit my paper, I have to catch the deadline, my problem is am a new in LaTeX and I have to submit my paper at [Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery journal](http://www.springer.com/computer/database+management+%26+information+retrieval/journal/10618?detailsPage=pltci_2554736)

I have already installed the TeXMaker editor and start writing my first LaTeX file.

How can I use their provided [LaTeX macro package](http://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX.zip)?
Any help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, journals will provide a class file which ends in `.cls` and certain BibTeX style files ending in `.bst`.  In order to use them, simply copy these files into the same directory as the master `.tex` file that requires them.  (Some journals also provide these packages through [CTAN](http://ctan.org), in which case, you need install them and there is no need to copy anything.)

When you have `\documentclass{foo}`, LaTeX will start by looking in the same directory for `foo.cls` and if it doesn't find it there, it will then go on to other set locations to try and find this file, and it is very similar with the BibTeX style files.

You should also have a look at their bundled `template.tex` as it should give a good idea of the format they are expecting, and also how to use the features they provide through their class file.

Answer (score 0):

Springer provides the svjour3 class for preparation of journal manuscripts. It is a generic class applicable to all Springer journals. The class establishes standard formatting for titles, body text and the bibliography.  It is based on the article class. The instructions indicate: "The main differences to the standard article class are the presence of additional high-level structuring commands for the article header, new environments for theorem-like structures, and some other useful commands."  The files for the current version (ver 3.3) are available here: ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3. There are various choices depending on the page size of target journal (A4 or A5), and article format (single or 2 columns).  Be sure to get the correct style file for the bibliography. There are several options, but you need spbasic.bst for *Data Mining ad Knowledge Discovery* journal. It is available here, along with choices appropriate for other journals: ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/svjour3/bibtex/. Authors are expected to use natbib commands to cite references. There are also useful instructions here about how to install and use the Springer journal class: http://waluyo-adi-siswanto.blogspot.my/2013/06/preparing-springer-article-manuscript.html. Note that the files here are v3.2.