# How to use template of this journal?

Tags: templates

I am trying to submit an article to a [journal](http://www.springer.com/physics/journal/12648). They have provided me template of their journal which is downloadable from from this [link](http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/injp+style.zip?SGWID=0-0-45-819199-p173873837), which is actually a zip file containing one class file and 7 Latex style files. Out of these, I need to use file named INJP. I am familiar with templates in .tex format and I could not understand how to use these files to prepare my manuscript according to their format.

Please help !

Comment: This answer may help you: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/292683/89098

Comment: @Ross: I can easily use svjour3 format of Springer because .tex file for template is also given in package. But for this journal no template in .tex is available. Although this journal is of Springer but it used different style.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

This will get you started. Unzip the archive to a folder. Make a new `tex` file, say `physicspaper.tex`. Then include this code for your MWE. After that, it is just like writing any LaTeX document.

```
\documentstyle[injp]{iacs} 
   \title{title}
   \author{author}
\begin{document}
   \maketitle   
   \section{Introduction}
   This is some text.
\end{document}
```

I gather from this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31843/89098) by @egreg, the requirement to use `\documentstyle` is a "dinosaur". Good luck.

Comment: A ***Huge*** warning will plop up tellng you that `documentstyle` is, like a dnosaur, extinct. It should not be used anymore. People have to update to current (already) 20 year old LaTeX2e.

Comment: @Johannes. Agree. But this "dinosaur" is what OP was given. Like you said, the publisher needs to update their class and style files.